# In NXT monetary system, how do you transfer the coins complete control to another account?

Tags: nxt

I purchased a few MS (monetary system) coins and i want to move it to another account completely. I want that other account to also be able to reissue this coin with new settings too. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to delete the coin in the old account using the API and for that you must possess all the coins. Then, create the coin in the new account.

Comment: doesnt that pose a risk of someone else snatching it up?